# JQuery simple search

Tags: jquery

I attempting to write a simple JQuery search.

This is what I have so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#search").bind("keydown", function() {
    if($("#search").val() != ''){
        $.get("/search", {phrase: $("#search").val()}, function(data) {
            $("#searchResults").html(data);
        });
    }else{
        $("#searchResults").html('');
    }

});
 });
```

The problem I am having is that when I press down a key the first letter is not sent to the server.  In addition, I have to hit backspace twice before the searchResults are cleared.

I have been using Firefox to observer the get requests.

For example, I press the key "f" and the phrase value passed via the get request is blank.  If I press "ff" then only "f" is sent via the get request.  I have to press backspace twice before the searchResults are cleared.

Does anyone know what the problem is or how I can change this to avoid this problem?

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind to the `keyup` event instead. You're sending the request before the current keystroke has been added to the value. The event order of key presses is `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`, and the value is updated between the press and up events.